# Why safeeyes is using internet?

Tags: linux

Safeeyes is software provide reminders to take a break. Why does it need to access network? safeeyes was seen in netstat using the network.

Comment: Could you clarify what was seen in `netstat`?

Comment: Please ask its developers instead: https://slgobinath.github.io/SafeEyes/

Answer (score 0):

It uses [remote procedure call](https://github.com/slgobinath/SafeEyes#features) (RPC) protocol as application programming interface (API).

In short it runs [it's own server](https://github.com/slgobinath/SafeEyes/blob/4638e075ca259f84ba10d8fb2cff1b72d1985df6/safeeyes/rpc.py#L20) as a *communication* interface to send commands via command-line. ([SimpleXMLRPCServer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.server.html))

It is possible [to disable](https://github.com/slgobinath/SafeEyes/commit/020dea888c88940d4883168e2bb0023ea50ead48) but in general not advised.

Discussed further here:

- [why port TCP/7200 is opened to any foreign address?](https://github.com/slgobinath/SafeEyes/issues/304)

It is intended for local use.